# Why does method 'Arrays.asList()' not accept arguments of type {"",""}, but accepts ("","")?

Tags: java, arrays

I am not new to Java `Collections`, but I have a confusion about the following scenario.

In my project I've implemented a code like this:

```
List<String> obj_lStr= new ArrayList<String>();
String[] obj_arrStr = {"someString", "noString", "abcString"};
obj_lStr.addAll(Arrays.asList(obj_arrStr));
```

but during code review my project lead gave me the instruction to change this code and implement it without using `String[] obj_arrStr`.

Then I changed my code to this:

```
obj_lStr.addAll(Arrays.asList( { "someString", "noString", "abcString" }));
```

but I got compilation errors:

```
Main.java:13: error: illegal start of expression
    x.addAll(Arrays.asList({"someString", "noString", "abcString"}));
                           ^
Main.java:13: error: ')' expected
    x.addAll(Arrays.asList({"someString", "noString", "abcString"}));
                            ^
Main.java:13: error: ';' expected
    x.addAll(Arrays.asList({"someString", "noString", "abcString"}));
```

and I change my line of code to this:

```
obj_lStr.addAll(Arrays.asList("someString", "noString", "abcString"));
```

then the compilation error is gone.

Question: Why is it so? Why `asList()` method raises a compilation error with `{"","",""}`, but not for `("","","")`?

Comment: Try to understand it by reading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29.

Comment: `{...}` is used for array initialization, `asList(T...)` requires `var-args`, meaning that you're not actually passing an array but a sequence of objects that together form the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the signature of `asList()` has the answer :`public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)`

it takes a varargs , so `obj_lStr.addAll(Arrays.asList("someString", "noString", "abcString"));`  compiles bcoz your arguments will be turned into an array.

but here `obj_lStr.addAll(Arrays.asList( { "someString", "noString", "abcString" }));`, you need to specify the type of the array. so you can do this : `obj_lStr.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "someString", "noString", "abcString" }));`.

the `{}` initialization syntax for arrays is available only during initilization , for ex:

```
int[] a ={1,2,4}; // works
```

but

```
int[] a new int[3];
a = {1,2,4}; // doesn't work
```

Answer (score 5):

`Arrays.asList` takes either an array, or all elements of the array as argument.

So you need either

```
Arrays.asList(new String[]{"someString", "noString", "abcString"})
```

or

```
Arrays.asList("someString", "noString", "abcString")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just to do with where in Java code you're allowed to omit the type and allow the array to be inferred -- specifically, you can only use `array = {foo, bar...}` when you're assigning directly into an array of the appropriate type, not where you're passing it around elsewhere.

In any event, what you should be writing is

```
Arrays.asList("someString", "noString", "abcString")
```

with no `{}` braces at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can either feed an String Array to `Arrays.asList`:

```
Arrays.asList(new String[] {"a","b","c"});
```

or with multiple Strings (varags)

```
Arrays.asList("a","b","c");
```

But just

```
Arrays.asList({"a","b","c"});
```

isnt working, as `{"a","b","c"}` does not represent an object an Java

Answer (score 0):

If you try looking at the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) 
, you'll learn that `asList` has the signature

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

Now, the argument declaration `T... a`, uses a feature of java called [variable arguments](http://www.javatpoint.com/varargs), which basically just means that the argument `a`, can either be an array of type T, or, it can be a sequence of objects all of type T.

Hope that helps.